# Luhn checksum in python

Tags: python

i've implemented Luhn checksum  and i want your opinion about my code

i know it's embarrassing code and doesn't follow python best practices but it works

```
import ast

def  doubledigit(n,x) :

    if x is  True:

        doubledigit = n *2
        sum=0
        if doubledigit >= 10 :
            sum = 1 + doubledigit % 10
        else: sum = doubledigit
    else:
       sum = n
return (sum)
def sum ():
   total =0
   prop = int(input("enter how many digits you want: " ))
   for i in range (0,prop):
       n = int(input("Enter your digit: " ))
       x = input("Enter True or False: ")
       total = total+doubledigit(n,ast.literal_eval(x))

   return total
def findx (n):
   if (n % 10 == 1 ):
      n += 9
   if (n % 10 == 2 ):
      n += 8
   if (n % 10 == 3 ):
      n += 7
   if (n % 10 == 4 ):
      n += 6
   if (n % 10 == 5 ):
      n += 5
   if (n % 10 == 6 ):
      n += 4
   if (n % 10 == 7 ):
      n += 3
   if (n % 10 == 8 ):
      n += 2
   if (n % 10 == 9 ):
      n += 1
   if (n % 10 == 0):
      print("vaild checksum")
return n
print(findx(sum()))
```

Comment: You should probably post this on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hello, you might want to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for replying.....i'm gonna post it now

Answer (score 0):

The Luhn algorithm, also known as the modulus 10 or mod 10 algorithm, is a simple checksum formula used to validate a variety of identification numbers, such as credit card numbers, IMEI numbers

```
def luhn_Algorithm(s):
    """Function to check whether given credit card number is valid or not"""
    n = len(s)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        output = 0
        if i % 2 != 0:
            output = 2 * int(s[i])
            if output > 9:
                first_digit = output % 10
                second_digit = (output // 10) % 10
                output = first_digit + second_digit
            sum = sum + output
        else:
            sum = sum + int(s[i])
    print(sum)
    return True if sum % 10 == 0 else False
```

Comment: Where did you copy this from?

Comment: its my own code, if u want, you can check in myscans

Comment: The description, though, is written word for word on several sites. Question seems to already know what the algorithm is. Also, this question is 4+ years old, and code in the question "works"